# Does libcurl load complete page in single shot?

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I'm using libcurl to fire HTTP request.

Does lincurl load complete page in single shot,
or for sub-links on page i.e. .css or. png file it request separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libcurl **does not** automatically send any sub-requests for any links in the requested resource. This would be a completely unreasonable behaviour for any linked media.

To retrieve linked media, you have to extract the links from the resource you initially retrieve, and then do separate requests for them as needed (just like a web browser does behind the scenes).

Comment: Exactly I'm asking that only, for linked media (i.e. css and .js ) libcurl sends separate requests. right?
One more query, do we have access/control to subsequent media link requests?

Comment: libcurl is agnostic to what the data it receives means, figuring that out is the job of the caller. If you want to load linked media from HTML that you receive, then as @CaptainGiraffe says, you will manually have  to scan the HTML and issue new libcurl requests yourself for those resources.

Comment: @Zenselezz even java script i.e. .js links won't be requested right?

Comment: @BSalunke Correct, it doesn't do anything with the data from the request except pass it back to you.

Comment: @BSalunke: libcurl simply downloads the *raw data* of the resource that you request. You have to then parse that data yourself and act on it accordingly. So, you would first download an HTML file, parse it, extract the links to its JavaScript files, and then send new libcurl requests to retrieve them individually.